# ASP.NET MVC Get full path of shared folder when call file.SaveAs method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two IIS: publicIIS and privateIIS. On publicIIS I create a shared folder which is named  "Data". I use privateIIS to upload file and save it to "Data". I use file.SaveAs() method but it required the root path. How do I retrieve full path of shared folder? Is it posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the network path when I pass to method SaveAs, it will get physical path.